# About the spatial distribution of vacuum energy around strongly gravitating objects in the galaxy

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter, dark-energy

We know that the distribution of vacuum energy is spatially uniform. But we also know that it couples to gravity.

Anything with energy, such as a beam of light is affected by the gravitational field of the matter distribution in the galaxy. Why shouldn't the vacuum energy also respond to or be affected by the gravitating masses in a galaxy? Why shouldn't the presence of a supermassive black hole at the center of the galaxy change the *spatial* distribution of vacuum energy around it from uniform to non-uniform?

This question may also be asked in the following manner. If the distribution of dark matter in the galaxy is affected by the distribution of luminous matter, why should the dark energy remain uniform defying any presence of luminous and non-luminous gravitating matter in the galaxy?

Comment: A cosmological constant is a geometrical property of spacetime and does not "couple to gravity" in any reasonable sense of the words. I think you need to clarify what you mean by "couples to gravity".

Comment: Well, I believe, the vacuum energy will give rise to a nonzero stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ in the RHS of Einstein's field equation and thus produce a gravitational field. @JohnRennie

Comment: You are assuming the "stuff" that is responsible for dark energy responds to gravitational fields, but this is not necessarily the case. A cosmological constant would not because it is a property of spacetime. Since we have no idea what is responsible for dark energy I think it is unwise to make any assumptions about it.

Comment: What should the attitude be? Dark energy is not any "stuff" but the energy of "stuff-free" empty space or energy of "nothing"? But one thing that bothers me is that dark energy is energy. If so, why is its gravitational response in a curved background different from that of real particles carrying energy such as photons? Is it like the following problem? Light or matter particles move or respond to curved spacetime is governed by the geodesic equation. It's not clear how "nothing" would respond to curved spacetime? Am I on the right track? @JohnRennie

Comment: Just to be clear: I am assuming that this vacuum energy is contributed by the zero-point energies of the quantum fields plus other energies coming from spontaneous symmetry breaking etc. Therefore, more than being a property of spacetime, it seems to me to be a property of the ground states of the fields living on spacetime. @JohnRennie